# Maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[2i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

We want to find a maximal ideal of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[2i]$. We guess that the ideal $I=(5,2i)$ generated by $5, 2i$ is a maximal ideal. All things I know about the ring are Noetherian, but not PID, UFD, Dedekind domain. How can we obtain the form of maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[2i]$?

Thanks for any hints on this problem.

Comment: Your example ideal is not maximal. $I=\Bbb{Z}[2i]$. For $(2i)^2=-4\in I$ and hence also $5-4=1\in I$. Do you know the maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept that $\mathbb Z[2i]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+4)$, then let us find a maximal ideal in the later ring. The maximal ideal $(2,X)$ of $\mathbb Z[X]$ contains $X^2+4$, so $(2,X)/(X^2+4)$ is a maximal ideal in the factor ring. It corresponds to the ideal $(2,2i)$ in $\mathbb Z[2i]$.

Comment: First of all thanks. Is it possible to construct a different maximal ideal in a similar way?

Comment: $(3,X^2+1)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[X]$ which contains $(X^2+4)$. It corresponds to the ideal $(3)$ in $\mathbb Z[2i]$. Similarly, one can try $(7,X^2-3)$. It corresponds to $(7)$.